# How to assign StringBuilder to String value at Android?

Tags: android

I have a dynamic message Stringbuilder value in my codes. 
But i want to create temp string and i want to save message value to temp value and than clean message value:
For example:

```
StringBuilder messages;
StringBuilder [] temp = new StringBuilder[1000];
...///other part of codes
temp[i]=message;
 String text=intent.getStringExtra("theMessage");
i++;
 messages.delete(0, messages.length());
```

A mean, when my **messages** come 34 i want to save *temp[0]* and clean **message** and i want to increase i with i++ and than message come 23 than *`temp[1]=2`3* and so on... How can i do this at android ?

Comment: did you try messages.toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its as simple as following:

```
    StringBuilder [] temp = new StringBuilder[1000];
    int index = 0;
    if(messages.length() == 34){
        temp[index] = new StringBuilder(messages);
        messages.delete(0, messages.length());
    }

    ...
```

If `temp[]` is of type `String` then simply

```
temp[index] = new StringBuilder(messages.toString())
```

Comment: Okey. I will 2 days later.